# Error:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.2.2:8080 refused

Tags: php, android, eclipse, rest

Error:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to `http://10.0.2.2:8080` refused  When Android consumes rest api in php, and I connect to the api

I use eclipse and my android phone via usb to run my app . My api rest is made in php and use xampp and it run on port 8080 `http://localhost:8080` . Xampp works with my other web application , but Android does not work.

-Also, my phone and my computer are not connected to the same network.
 -rest api can work in this case without internet?

My code in android is this :

```
 private class TareaWSInsertar extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {
        //agregado user_id, user_fullname, user_email
        private int user_id;
        private String user_fullname;
        private  String user_email;

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            boolean resul = true;

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/rest/login/");
        post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        try
            {
            //Construimos el objeto cliente en formato JSON
            JSONObject dato = new JSONObject();


            dato.put("email", params[0]);
            dato.put("pwd", params[1]);

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dato.toString());
            post.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
                String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

                JSONObject respJSON = new JSONObject(respStr);

                user_id = respJSON.getInt("user_id");
                user_fullname = respJSON.getString(user_fullname);
                user_email = respJSON.getString("user_email");


                if(!respStr.equals("true"))
                    resul = false;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("ServicioRest","Error!", ex);
                resul = false;
            }

            return resul;
        }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

            if (result)
            {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + user_id+ "-" +    user_fullname + "-" + user_email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried different way :

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/rest/login
 http://localhost:8080/rest/login
 http:/127.0.0.1:8080/rest/login
```

Note: I read that `http://10.0.2.2` only works when the android emulator is used,
I use my phone connected via usb .

but nothing works , even `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` I added in my manifest .

Sorry help me!!, PD: I do not speak English

Comment: `http:/127.0.0.1:8080/rest/login/`  is this a typos ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have an error:

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost ( " http:/127.0.0.1:8080/rest/login/ ");
```

should be:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost ( " http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/login/ ");
```

Next if the phone is not connected to your coputer network it wont ever connect to your local server aka your computer.

If you have a wifi connection at your home check the ip address of the computer which runs xampp and replace it with `localhost`. If there is no wifi connection and your computer if connected to your modem (without router) then just check your ip address [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) and replace it with `localhost`.

Comment: it is a different question :). please accept this one and ask a different one and I will be glad to help

Comment: @slowFly , pls open a new question. Then add link in the comment. I'll gladly help you.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this problem by writing my IP address from cmd -> ipconfig in the url:

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.x.x/rest/login/");